# Crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS on touch method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am currently working on a game which, seems to crash when accessing a certain part of the code which involves touching an item.

Here is the part of the code that crashes;

```
 drawOn = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, currentDrawingImage.size.width/2, currentDrawingImage.size.height/2)];
```

The full method is here;

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
    {
        BOOL foundExtra = NO;
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        for(int i = 0; i < [extrasArray count]; i++)
        {
            if([[[extrasArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"tag"] intValue] == [touch view].tag)
            {
                touchedExtra = YES;
                lastTouchedExtra = (int)[touch view].tag;
                foundExtra = YES;
            }
        }

        if(foundExtra == NO)
        {
            if(movingStopped == NO)
            {
                drawOn = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, currentDrawingImage.size.width/2, currentDrawingImage.size.height/2)];
                drawOn.image = currentDrawingImage;
                drawOn.tag = lastTag + 1;
                lastTag++;

                CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
                drawOn.center = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
                [bigView addSubview:drawOn];
                 lastTouchedPoint = touchPoint;
            }
        }

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    if(touchedExtra == YES)
    {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

        int indexIngr = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < [extrasArray count]; i++)
        {
            if([[[extrasArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"tag"] intValue] == [touch view].tag)
            {
                indexIngr = i;
                [touch view].center = touchPoint;
            }
        }

        NSMutableDictionary *md = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [md setObject:[[extrasArray objectAtIndex:indexIngr] objectForKey:@"pic"] forKey:@"pic"];
        [md setObject:NSStringFromCGRect([touch view].frame) forKey:@"frame"];
        [md setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[touch view].tag] forKey:@"tag"];

        [extrasArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexIngr withObject:md];


        //        if([touch view].tag > 0)
        //        {
        //            [touch view].center = touchPoint;
        //
        //            int tagLabel = [touch view].tag;
        //            NSMutableDictionary *md = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        //            [md setObject:[[ingredients objectAtIndex:tagLabel - 1] objectForKey:@"pic"] forKey:@"pic"];
        //            [md setObject:NSStringFromCGRect([touch view].frame) forKey:@"frame"];
        //
        //            [ingredients replaceObjectAtIndex:tagLabel - 1 withObject:md];
        //        }
    }
    else if(lastDecoration == 1)//draw on apple
    {
        if(movingStopped == NO)
        {
            CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
            if([self isFarEnoughFrom:touchPoint])
            {
                drawOn = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, currentDrawingImage.size.width/2, currentDrawingImage.size.height/2)];
                drawOn.image = currentDrawingImage;
                drawOn.tag = lastTag;


                drawOn.center = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
                [bigView addSubview:drawOn];
                //[self.view insertSubview:drawOn belowSubview:backButton];

                lastTouchedPoint = touchPoint;
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    touchedExtra = NO;
    //movingStopped = YES;
    lastTouchedExtra = -1;
}
```

The drawOnChosen method is used also;

```
- (void)drawOnChosen:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] playSoundEffect:1];

    currentDrawingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"drawon%d.png", (int)sender.tag]];
    movingStopped = NO;
    lastDecoration = 1;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^
     {
         decorationsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
     } completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [decorationsView removeFromSuperview];
     }];
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the line, and see if `currentDrawingImage` is valid. I assume `drawOn` is a class-level property or variable?

Comment: draw0n is a `UIImageView *drawOn;`
I get this for currentDrawingImage `(UIImage *) currentDrawingImage = 0x000000017428a410`

Comment: Are you getting any other error / crash information (you must be)? Split up the line - do `CGFloat w = currentDrawingImage.size.width / 2; CGFloat h = currentDrawingImage.size.height / 2;` and *then* `drawOn = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h)];` and see where the crash actually occurs.

Comment: If I do what you said there, it actually crashes on the line I added that you suggested; 

`GFloat w = currentDrawingImage.size.width / 2; CGFloat h = currentDrawingImage.size.height / 2;`

Comment: So, that tells you that `currentDrawingImage` is not valid at that point. Time to figure out why you are trying to use it before it's been initialized.

Comment: Still trying to figure it out :(

Comment: From what you've shown of your code, you can get to a line that references `currentDrawingImage` ***before*** you initialize or set it to a valid object. Where in your code are you creating it before `touchesBegan` gets called?

Comment: I have added another part of the code which is `touchesMoved` I added to my original question.
I can only see a reference to `currentDrawingImage` in those methods, and in the `CandyDecoViewController.h` which is just;

`UIImage *currentDrawingImage;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138257/discussion-between-donmag-and-hypergater).